# How to go to the next iteration in a list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Let me explain my problem.
I have a list of path in a dict, and I want to iterate through this dict in order to verify if the path to a folder contains a certain type of file, let's say a .txt file. But each Key may contain thousand of path links which contains may a .txt file or not and         I just want to verify if at least a value of each key contains a .txt (at least one), my current code works but continue to iterate through all the other values of the key, and then if the key has many values, the code can be long to run and return many times the same value, I can remove the duplicates from the final dict but as I said  the code would take too much time to process and it's not optimal given that my actual "test" dict contains a lot of keys

```
test={'Info': ['//home/info/folder1','//home/info/folder2','//home/info/folder3'], 'Courses' : ['//home/courses/math', '//home/courses/Physics','//home/courses/Bio' ]}

def fct(ListNames):
    listFile = {}
    for i in ListNames:
        for j in (ListNames[i]):
            for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(str(j)):
                for file in filenames:
                    if re.match(r'.*\.txt$',file) != None :  
                        listFile.setdefault(i, []).append((1))

    return(listFile)
print(fct(test))
```

my output is :

```
{ 'Info': [1, 1, 1], 'Courses': [1, 1] }
```

Meaning for The Key 'Info' all the 3 paths contain at least a file.txt and for the key 'Courses' only two paths contain at least a file.txt (I don't mind to know which one contains it )

I would like to just have this output :

```
{ 'Info': [1], 'Courses': [1] }
```

or

```
{ 'Info': 1, 'Courses': 1 }
```

Meaning, at least one path in 'Info' and 'Courses' contains a 'file.txt' but after finding one, it went to look at the other keys and not iterating for nothing the rest of the values.

I was thinking about using cycle from itertools or using enumerate but I can't make it work.
I guess It would simply consist on incrementing the next "i" in my Listname after the if statement but i don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `any` to stop an iteration as soon as the first true result is returned.  Here's a way to do it in a dict comprehension, with a nested generator expression in an `any` call that decides whether to include the key in the dict or not:

```
from os import walk

def fct(list_names: dict[str, list[str]]) -> dict[str, int]:
    return {
        k: 1 for k, paths in list_names.items()
        if any(
            f.endswith(".txt") 
            for path in paths
            for _, _, filenames in walk(path)
            for f in filenames
        ) 
    }
```

The generator expression in the `any` call:

```
f.endswith(".txt") for path in paths for _, _, filenames in walk(path) for f in filenames
```

is equivalent to a generator function with a nested loop in it:

```
from os import walk
from typing import Iterator

def files_ending_with_txt(paths: list[str]) -> Iterator[bool]:
    for path in paths:
        for _, _, filenames in walk(path):
            for f in filenames:
                yield f.endswith(".txt")
```

which has the same basic structure as the loop in your function; the difference is that a generator can be "stopped" before it's run to completion (by simply not continuing to pull items from it).